# How to Send a CSV File as Request in Body

Tags: java, csv, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm trying to send a csv file as a request in body.

It's working fine for me in Postman. But I'm getting the below error in Jmeter.

```json
{
   "id":32,
   "deleted":null,
   "uuid":"f5cec747-4794-4e54-9c4b-58da61f30921",
   "status":"Error",
   "csvFileName":"",
   "unsuccessfulRecords":[
      "['Not Applicable', '{\\'csvFile\\': [ErrorDetail(string=\\'The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.\\', code=\\'invalid\\')], \\'assets\\': [ErrorDetail(string=\\'Expected a list of items but got type \"str\".\\', code=\\'not_a_list\\')]}']"
   ],
   "successfulRecordsCount":0,
   "duplicateRecordsCount":0,
   "createdBy":"user",
   "createdAt":"2022-12-06T09:58:51.285524Z",
   "modifiedAt":"2022-12-06T09:58:51.285538Z",
   "idAllowdAt":"2022-12-06T09:58:51.285538Z",
   "idAllowListType":1
}
```

Below is the request i'm sending as part of Body Data. The REST Api accept these parameters, and afer that it imports the CSV file:

```
{
    "csvFile": "${__FileToString(D:/Users/anabeel/Downloads/Demo/Demo.csv,,)}",
    "allowlistTypeId": "1",
    "createdBy": "user",
    "assets": "['asset1', 'asset2']",
    "uuid": "${requestIndex}",
    "tags": "{'Platform Family':[{'abc123':'LinuxOS System'}]}",
    "tenantId": "abc456"
}
```

Content-type: application/json

It seems I'm not importing the csv file the right way. Can someone please help me as I dont have much experience working with Jmeter. I also tried using CSV Data Set Config, but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: What's the request header in POSTMAN vs the request header in JMeter? Hint: "application/json" might not be the right content type header for JMeter.

Comment: I'm only specifying bearer token in request header in postman. For Jmeter, I'm specifying the bear token and the content-type.

Comment: Content-type in postman is: multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>

Comment: Check DMitri's response. That should help. I believe something is off with your headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your request "working fine for me in Postman" you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html).

1. Configure JMeter for recording, the easiest option is going for [Recording Template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building)
2. [Import JMeter's certificate to Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)

   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyS8j.png]
4. **Copy your CSV file to bin folder of your JMeter installation**
5. Run your request in Postman
6. JMeter will generate proper [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
7. [Parameterize](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) the path to the CSV file if needed
8. Your JMeter request should be working fine now

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)